# Denied entry into Dubai: how soon can I get a new visa

Tags: visas, dubai, removal

I was denied entry into Dubai at Dubai International Airport. How soon can I make a new visa request to travel back there?

Comment: It would help to know the reason(s) for the refusal, and to see the notice you were given. Are you able to scan and upload it to your question with your personal details obscured (such as name, passport number)? Was this a visa on arrival, or one granted to you prior to travel?